# Saving data to an Excel file but too many entries

Tags: python, excel

I am using [this script](https://gitlab.com/greenbeast/selenium_web_scrape/-/blob/main/web_scrape.py) to grab a CSV from a local microcontroller and am storing the information in an Excel file. The issue I am running into is I hit the limit for how many entries can be in an Excel file so I need to find a way to adapt the script to say something like

```
if excel_file == full:
    open new excel sheet and print data there
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the exact error in case anyone is curious:

```
ValueError('This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 1744517, 27 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384')
```

Comment: Is the limit a fixed number of rows/columns?  Or does it vary by the amount of data in each cell?

Comment: I believe it is a fixed number of rows. Something like 1.5 million. I added in the error it throws.

Comment: My first recommendation would be to not use Excel :) but if that's what you need, is all of the data being written once or is the file being opened and closed? If it's being written at once just count the number of rows and when you get to the max value, write the excel file start a new.

Comment: I wish I could not use Excel but unfortunately people in the office really like it. It is all being written at once so I can look into having it count entries then open a new sheet when the limit is hit. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Keep track of the number of rows you've written, and stop once you reach 1048576.

Comment: Take a look at the solution in the first comment [here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578045-split-up-text-file-by-line-count/) for a method to split a file by line count into smaller files. Then you could put each in a separate worksheet. Though I have my doubts that a person can get much out of looking at 1.5 million lines in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting everything into a pandas dataframe and using

```
df_1 = df.iloc[:1000000,:]
df_2 = df.iloc[1000001:,:]
```

which splits the df after a million entries then added them to different sheets of the same Excel file.